# I'm having a hard time understanding why this is returning x is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a hard time understanding why this is returning "5Style is not a function"

```js
NationalLevelCategoriesChosenList = [
  ["5Style", "5MelodyHarmony", "5RhythmTempo", "5TextureStructureForm", "5Timbre"]
], [
  []
];

if (NationalLevelCategoriesChosenList[0].some("5Style")) {
  console.log("working")
}
```

Comment: Because [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) expects a function, not a string. Perhaps you meant [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `some()` function allows you to [test a value with a provided function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). I think you want to use `includes()` instead ? Please see snippet below.

```js
NationalLevelCategoriesChosenList = [
  ["5Style", "5MelodyHarmony", "5RhythmTempo", "5TextureStructureForm", "5Timbre"]
], [
  []
];


if (NationalLevelCategoriesChosenList[0].includes('5Style')){
  console.log("working")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for `some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

The argument you are passing `"5Style"` is a string, not a function.

You are probably looking for [the `includes` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
NationalLevelCategoriesChosenList[0].includes("5Style")
```

But if you wanted to use `some` then you need to write a function:

```
NationalLevelCategoriesChosenList[0].some((current_value) => curent_value === "5Style")
```